# Regex for city with Apostrophe

Tags: regex, validation

Here's is my javascript regex for a city name and it's handling almost all cases except this.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[\. - ']?(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

(Should pass)

- Coeur d'Alene
- San Tan Valley
- St. Thomas
- St. Thomas-Vincent
- St. Thomas Vincent
- St Thomas-Vincent
- St-Thomas
- anaconda-deer lodge county

(Should Fail)

- San. Tan. Valley
- St.. Thomas
- St.. Thomas--Vincent
- St.- Thomas -Vincent
- St--Thomas

Comment: Can you clarify the matching criteria a little?  Why should `San. Tan. Valley` fail?

Comment: @willOEM Because I am not aware of a city with two periods.

Comment: Ok, but looking from the outside, we do not know the context of what you are trying to match.  I would imagine that if you were trying to parse externally-sourced or user-supplied content, `San. Tan. Valley` would be acceptable because it is not grammatically incorrect.  Just my two cents.

Comment: I placed the requirements of what I need to pass and fail for my project.  So that is what I am modeling the regex around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:[.'\-,])?\s?)+$
```

This does match:

> Coeur d'Alene
>   San Tan Valley
>   St. Thomas
>   St. Thomas-Vincent
>   St. Thomas Vincent
>   St Thomas-Vincent
>   St-Thomas
>   anaconda-deer lodge county
>   Monte St.Thomas
>   San. Tan. Valley
>   Washington, D.C.

But doesn't match:

> St.. Thomas
>   St.. Thomas--Vincent
>   St.- Thomas -Vincent
>   St--Thomas

(I allowed it to match `San. Tan. Valley`, since there's probably a city name out there with 2 periods.)

How the regex works:

```
# ^         - Match the line start.
# (?:       - Start a non-catching group
# [a-zA-Z]+ - That starts with 1 or more letters.
# [.'\-,]?  - Followed by one period, apostrophe dash, or comma. (optional)
# \s?       - Followed by a space (optional)
# )+        - End of the group, match at least one or more of the previous group.
# $         - Match the end of the line
```

Comment: I would not allow delimiters in the end. This also matches `Yan' St-`

Comment: @Bergi: `Washington, D.C.`

Comment: OK, I think we can always find locations with other characters that are not matched…

Comment: Yeap, There's no end to a arms race like that :P

Comment: This got me close enough, as there will always be that one, thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

This matches all your names from the first list and not those from the second:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.(?!-))?(?:[\s-](?:[a-z]+')?[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

Multiline explanation:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+     # begins with a word
(?:\.(?!-))?   # maybe a dot but not followed by a dash
(?:
 [\s-]         # whitespace or dash
 (?:[a-z]+\')? # maybe a lowercase-word and an apostrophe
 [a-zA-Z]+     # word
)*$            # repeated to the end
```

To allow the dots anywhere, but not two of them, use this:

```
/^(?!.*?\..*?\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\.\s?|\s|-)(?:[a-z]+')?[a-zA-Z]+)*$/

^(?!.*?\..*?\.) # does not contain two dots
[a-zA-Z]+       # a word
(?:
 (?:\.\s?|\s|-) # delimiter: dot with maybe whitespace, whitespace or dash
 (?:[a-z]+\')?  # maybe a lowercase-word and an apostrophe
 [a-zA-Z]+      # word
)*$             # repeated to the end
```

Comment: Can't get that one to match anything on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=&input=Coeur%20d'Alene%0ASan%20Tan%20Valley%0ASt.%20Thomas%0ASt.%20Thomas-Vincent%0ASt.%20Thomas%20Vincent%0ASt%20Thomas-Vincent%0ASt-Thomas%0Aanaconda-deer%20lodge%20county%0A%0AMonte%20St.Thomas%0A%0ASan.%20Tan.%20Valley%0ASt..%20Thomas%0ASt..%20Thomas--Vincent%0ASt.-%20Thomas%20-Vincent%0ASt--Thomas) (Paste your regex in there, this url breaks when I try to link it with the regex in it.)

Comment: Unless I am doing something wrong it's not finding any matches using http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Uh, I forgot some quantifiers after the word characters :-/ Should work now for all cases from your question.

Comment: Failed for `Monte St.Thomas`, though. Also, could you explain the regex a bit, please?

Comment: @Cerbrus: That was not in your list. I expected you wanted to allow the dot only after the first word? If you want to allow it everywhere, but only once (as stated in the other comments), it gets far more complicated.

Comment: @Bergi: Not my question. And no, the regex would be simpler. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following regexp fits your requirements :

```
^([Ss]t\. |[a-zA-Z ]|\['-](?:[^-']))+$
```

On the other hand, you may question the idea of using a regexp to do that... Whatever the complexity of your regexp, there will always be some fool finding a new unwanted pattern that matches...

Usually when you need to have valid city names, it's better to use some geocoding api, like [google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: Fails on `Monte St.Thomas`

Comment: As well, none with the dashes are passing? I am using http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx